# Searching upon values in worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets with IDS. The first one have much more than 2nd. My task is to check if ID from 2nd worksheet is available in first worksheet and if it is, then I need to change cell content of ID from sheet 1 to "Not in use"

I've tried this way but without success

```
        Set Search_ID_Range_Sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, LastRow_Sh1) ' "c" is the column number of ID column in main (1st) worksheet

        Set Search_ID_Range_Sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(2, LastRow_Sh2)
    
    For Each ID1 In Search_ID_Range_Sh1
        For Each ID2 In Search_ID_Range_Sh2
            If ID1 = ID2 Then
              Cells(i, c).Value = ID2.Offset(0.1).Value 'Not in use
            End If
        Next ID2
    Next ID1
```

Answer (score 1):

You use cells index wrong in your code. You swaped index column with row. i think loop inside loop and checking all of datas singly its wrong method for that case.
try use find method its much easier

```
Sub SearchID()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim CheckID As String
    Dim FindRange As Range
    
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set WS1 = WB.Worksheets(1)
    Set WS2 = WB.Worksheets(2)
    
    For i = 2 To WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        CheckID = WS2.Cells(i, 2)   '   column b
        Set FindRange = WS1.Cells.Find(CheckID)
        If Not FindRange Is Nothing Then
            WS1.Cells(FindRange.Row, 3) = "Not in use"  '   column c
        End If  '   If Not FindRange Is Nothing
        Set FindRange = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```